# Why is "/usr/lib/upower/upowerd" consuming 100% cpu causing freezes for seconds, frequently

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, lag

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and today it suddenly started freezing up frequently for seconds on end.

When I check the running processes it seems that a process called "upowerd" is hogging up the CPU causing lag spikes rendering my system useless.

I tried disabling this service and killing the process hoping to fix it but it keeps starting again.

Note, I don't have an iPhone, I have a mouse and a keyboard connected through USB and an external monitor connected through HDMI. My laptops battery is pretty much dead so I always use it connected to the power.

Any help is appreciated as I'm not able to play any games or even properly use my laptop anymore.

Please let me know if there are any extra info I can provide to help debug the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this [Disabling upowerd on a Desktop Linux computer that never actually had a battery.](https://dirkmittler.homeip.net/blog/archives/9223) ? (Ubuntu is Debian based...)

Comment: Yes I have tried this.

Comment: Is there a way to bump this? I desperately need help

Comment: This site and it's related sites do not work that way. Please read the site's community guidelines, and understand what the purpose of the site is--We are not paid technical support to prioritize your issues, just users and volunteers much like you.

Comment: What all *have* you tried so far? Your question has very little information to help us help you... (You said you tried the steps in the link I gave. What exactly did you do? Edit your question to show the steps you took, and the results of each step. Do not reply in the comments here--put it in the question so others waning to help can immediately see it.)

Comment: Hello, I'm perfectly aware that people here are volunteers and are not paid. I also mentioned, if there are any info I can provide I can gladly do that. I've tried disabling the upower service and killing it and this is mentioned in the question itself. I'm not sure what else to try at this point. This is why I'm here and asking for opinions/help of others if they have an idea where I might go and try debugging this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did you kill upowerd, or did you shut it down properly and disable it? If killed, it may be restarting on the logic that something went wrong and it needs to restart. Shutting it down usually bypasses a restart, and disabling makes it not (re)load at all, even when you reboot. "I rebooted" could mean a proper shutdown and reboot, or it could mean you pulled the power plug out and risked file system corruption. This is why we ask you to show us the exact steps you try--sometimes there are many ways to do the same thing, but with subtle differences and results.

Comment: I tried killing it, with and without sudo, I tried disabling the "upower" service. These have not worked fully. When I reboot my pc, it starts fine, until upowerd shows up (when it starts), I can see a "battery full" icon at the top of my screen and I start lagging. When I kill the "upowerd" in htop this disappears. When it starts again on its own shortly after, the icon doesn't show up. Other side effects are, when it starts for the first time I lose my touchpad and keyboard, they don't work until restart (regardless of upowerd running or not). I've just noticed this late as using externals.

Comment: As a *temporary* measure: As `root`, find and rename the `upowerd` binary to something such as `upowerd.disabled`, and possibly create an empty `upowerd` file in it's place (or copy a binary that does nothing except exit with a success code, such as `/bin/true`). This will *not* solve/fix the issue, but it may push it aside while you find a proper fix.

Comment: But don't replace the upowerd executable with the "ls" executable, because then your Ubuntu will not boot anymore, at least it will not get to the login part (happened to me on Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo y700) and you'll be looking at a black screen for a very long time.

Comment: Actually, I tried all 3 options C. M. suggests, but they all result in my ubuntu not completing boot. So be careful!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue. What worked for me was to use `htop` to `SIGKILL` the process. You would need to run `htop` with escalated privileges (`sudo`) in order to do so. Pressing the <kbd>F9</kbd> button while `htop` is running will present you with different options to kill the process. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, this works for the very short term, but it starts very soon once again, unfotrunately this is an unsustainable solution as I can't keep doing this.